# Ionic 4 toolbar not aligning

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using angular 8/ionic 4.  Has anyone seen this problem with the toolbar not aligning:

[image]

Here is the code I have for the footer of tab2.page.html:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Send To...</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only color="royal" (click)="displayAdd()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I created a tabs application using ionic start command.

Comment: your buttons use ionic 3 syntax , can you update it with Ionic 4?

Comment: Thank you Sergey, that was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergey, that was the answer!  I had to update some of the code to Ionic 4 syntax:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="create" color="royal"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="displayAdd()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add" color="royal"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```